Unable to get VBA code to work which allows data to be copied from one worksheet to another based on the selection of data from a drop down list
How can I copy the entire row to another worksheet based on the chosen item out of a dropdown list. If option 1 in Cell E2 which contains a dropdown list is selected I want to copy the row to Worksheet 2 and if option 2 in cell E2 which contains a dropdown list is selected I want to copy the row to Worksheet 3 and if option 3 in cell E2 which contains a dropdown list is selected I want to copy the row to Worksheet 4 etc
Option 1 would be Active which is found as an option of the drop down lost which is found on tab 2 called Data Validation in Cell A1
Option 2 would be pending which is found as an option of the drop down lost which is found on tab 2 called Data Validation in Cell A4
Option 3 would be renewed which is found as an option of the drop down lost which is found on tab 2 called Data Validation in Cell A5
Now tab1 Called All if Cell E2 was changed to Active then I want the entire row to be copied to the tab 3 called Active where as if the next cell E3 was changed to Pending from the drop down list then that entire row would be copied to Tab 4 called Pending and if it were changed to Renewed it would be copied to the tab 5 called Renewed.
I have tried the following VBA code but it does not work
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCell As Range
    Set KeyCell = Range("E2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then

        Select Case KeyCell.Value
            Case "Active"
                Call CopyRow(Target.Row, "Sheet3")
            Case "Pending"
                Call CopyRow(Target.Row, "Sheet4")
            Case "Renewed"
                Call CopyRow(Target.Row, "Sheet5")

            ' Add more cases as needed

        End Select
    End If

End Sub

Sub CopyRow(rowNumber As Integer, sheetName As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Rows(rowNumber & ":" & rowNumber).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sheetName).Rows(lastRow)
End Sub

Once i chose something from the drop down list it failed to copy the data to the relevant worksheet.

Call CopyRow(Target.Row, "Sheet3") - Target.Row will always be row 2 as Worksheet.Change fires when you change the value in a cell and you've just selected an item from cell E2.  Which row do you want it to copy?

A Worksheet Change: Copy to Worksheet Specified by Drop-Down
Main
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim keyCell As Range: Set keyCell = Me.Range("E2")

    If Intersect(keyCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = keyCell.EntireRow
    
    Dim dSheetName As String
    
    Select Case LCase(CStr(keyCell.Value))
        Case "active": dSheetName = "Sheet3"
        Case "pending": dSheetName = "Sheet4"
        Case "renewed": dSheetName = "Sheet5"
        ' Add more cases as needed
        'Case Else ' neither; do nothing?
    End Select
    
    If Len(dSheetName) > 0 Then CopyEntireRow rrg, dSheetName

End Sub

Help
Sub CopyEntireRow(sourceEntireRow As Range, DestinationSheetName As String)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = sourceEntireRow.Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
        
    Dim dws As Worksheet, dcell As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(DestinationSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet named """ & DestinationSheetName _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """ located at """ & wb.Path _
            & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If dws Is sws Then
        MsgBox "Cannot modify (source) worksheet """ & sws.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        With .Cells(1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1)
            If .Row = dws.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "The worksheet """ & dws.Name & """ is full!", _
                    vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Set dcell = .Offset(1).EntireRow.Columns("A")
        End With
    End With
    
    sourceEntireRow.Copy Destination:=dcell

End Sub

